# segmentation fault in code

Tags: c++, csv, vector, segmentation-fault

I am a newbie when it comes to c++, what I am trying to do is read from .csv file and and store it in vectors and then to be displayed, my problem is that the code crashes after the last reqd entry is displayed from the file when running from terminal, but in ide (codeblocks) it says sigsegv error when I try to debug it...

ps: the reason I want the read the file into vectors is to be able to enter into mysqldb later

```
#include <vector>
#include <string>
#include <sstream>
#include<fstream>
#include <iostream>

using namespace std;
vector<string> split_at_commas(const string& row)
{
    vector<string> res;
    istringstream buf(row);
    string s;
    while (getline(buf, s, ','))
        res.push_back(s);
    return res;
 }

int main()
{
    string line;
    ifstream  data("Book1.csv" ,ios::out);
    while(!data.eof())
    {
        getline(data,line,'\n');
        vector<string> v = split_at_commas(line);
        /*ide points error to this line*/ 
        cout << v[0] << '\t' << v[1] <<'\t' << v[2]<< '\t'<<endl;                  
    }
    data.close();
}
```

Comment: Your code indentation is terrible and you should feel terrible. Please fix

Comment: Can you post your data file - you may have one row that doesn't have three columns, so you are trying to access an element that does not exist.

Comment: most likely, your last record has less than 3 values, which makes `v[2]` violate array's boundary.

Comment: Difficult to say, maybe you are accessing v at the wrong index (out of range). Why don't you check the size of v first....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no guarantee that 'v' holds three or more elements. Check the content of 'v' after the call to split_at_commas and before the print in a debugger to verify that v holds 3 or more items.

Comment: Or better yet, use an iterator to loop through each entry. That way you will only print as many actual entries are there.

Comment: Great general approach and definitely a good option here. I assumed his input file would always have three words per line, so if there's anything in v, it's going to be three elements. For other scenarios, your suggestion is even better.

Comment: @fayyazkl      thanks a lot man i just put the output in a loop and it works,the loop is as follows 
     `for(unsigned int i=0;i<v.size();i++)`